# Packer Ansible provisioner is skipping tasks in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, packer

I am using the Packer Ansible provisioner in a JSON file to download a zip file from the web that contains a program and have that program run at startup by editing the Windows Registry using the `win_regedit` Ansible module:

```
---

- hosts: default
  tasks:
  - name: Create Bginfo Directory
    win_file:
      path: C:\Bginfo
      state: directory

  - name: Download BgInfo64.zip
    win_get_url:
     url: https://download.sysinternals.com/files/BGInfo.zip
     dest: C:\Bginfo\BgInfo64.zip

  - name: Unzip BgInfo64.zip
    win_unzip:
      src: C:\Bginfo\BgInfo64.zip
      dest: C:\Bginfo
      delete_archive: true

  - name: Run Bginfo at startup
    win_regedit:
      key: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
      name: Bginfo
      data: C:\Bginfo\Bginfo64.exe C:\BgInfo\default.bgi /timer:0 /nolicprompt
      type: string
```

When I check the machine, the registry edits were not made and the archive is not deleted after un-zipping.

As per the logs, `win_regedit` is using module file Using module file /opt/ansible/ansible/lib/ansible/modules/windows/win_regedit.ps1

`win_unzip` is using /opt/ansible/ansible/lib/ansible/modules/windows/win_unzip.ps1

I looked up the PowerShell files online and everything I'm doing seems legal by Ansible standards so I'm unsure why those tasks are not completed.

Comment: Try executing with `PACKER_LOG=1` to see specific Ansible errors. Alternatively, you can try executing the Ansible tasks outside of the Packer provisioner to test.

Comment: I tested outside of Packer in an Ansible environment and all Windows modules work. Where would I initialize PACKER_LOG to troubleshoot?

Comment: It would be an environment variable.